# How to add to a list of matrices in R?

Tags: r

Given a dataset `'train'` that has `1607` rows and `256` columns, I want to make each row (with `256` elements each) a `16x16` matrix and have a list to hold `1607` of such matrices. All observations in the `train` data are values between `-1` and `1`. For example, a row vector in the `train` could be

```
a <- seq(from = -1, to = 1, length = 256)
```

When I try to run a loop like this,

```
x <- lapply(1:nrow(train), matrix, data=0, nrow=16, ncol=16) #creates list of 1607 matrices of 0's
for (i in length(x)) {
   x[[i]] <- matrix(X_train[i,], nrow=16, ncol=16) #replace each element (matrix) of list x with a matrix of the same dimension from train
}
```

I keep getting the same unmodified list `x` with matrices of `0` for all elements of `x`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please make this question reproducible, including sample data either from your `train` (and `X_train`) or from something default (such as `mtcars` or `iris`).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for (i in length(x)) {
> ```

Here, you are looping over *one* value, namely, `length(x)`. You probably want to loop over all values from 1 to the length of `x`. You do this with

```
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
```

or

```
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
```

The latter has the benefit that it won't produce a bad result if `x` is empty. But really, you don't need to make a loop at all, or produce a list of blank matrices which you immediately discard. Instead, do:

```
rows <- seq_len(nrow(X_train))
x <- lapply(rows, function(row) matrix(X_train[row, ], nrow=16, ncol=16))
```

Comment: Wow, that was dumb of me. Thanks!